# JOLT transform that mixes common register data with array

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

Trying to make this transformation without success. From this input json (obtained from prometheus API which may not be relevant):

```json
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "hrStorageDescr",
          "hrStorageDescr": "/",
          "hrStorageIndex": "31",
          "instance": "instance1",
          "job": "snmp_linux_storage"
        },
        "values": [ [ 1687748400, "1" ], [ 1687748460, "2" ] ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "hrStorageDescr",
          "hrStorageDescr": "/var",
          "hrStorageIndex": "7",
          "instance": "instance2",
          "job": "snmp_linux_storage"
        },
        "values": [ [ 1687748400, "1" ], [ 1687748460, "2" ] ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "hrStorageDescr",
          "hrStorageDescr": "/",
          "hrStorageIndex": "31",
          "instance": "instance3",
          "job": "snmp_linux_storage"
        },
        "values": [ [ 1687748400, "1" ], [ 1687748460, "2" ] ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to transform to this output, associating common data from the metric record to each of the values of the values array, and output as an array of records:

```json
[
  {
    "hrStorageDescr": "/",
    "hrStorageIndex": "31",
    "instance": "instance1",
    "job": "snmp_linux_storage",
    "timestamp": 1687748400,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "hrStorageDescr": "/",
    "hrStorageIndex": "31",
    "instance": "instance1",
    "job": "snmp_linux_storage",
    "timestamp": 1687748460,
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "hrStorageDescr": "/var",
    "hrStorageIndex": "7",
    "instance": "instance2",
    "job": "snmp_linux_storage",
    "timestamp": 1687748400,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "hrStorageDescr": "/var",
    "hrStorageIndex": "7",
    "instance": "instance2",
    "job": "snmp_linux_storage",
    "timestamp": 1687748460,
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "hrStorageDescr": "/",
    "hrStorageIndex": "31",
    "instance": "instance3",
    "job": "snmp_linux_storage",
    "timestamp": 1687748400,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "hrStorageDescr": "/",
    "hrStorageIndex": "31",
    "instance": "instance3",
    "job": "snmp_linux_storage",
    "timestamp": 1687748460,
    "value": "2"
  }
]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deep dive upto the innermost array(**`"values"`**), and tile the identifiers as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "result": {
          "*": { // the level of the "result" array which is represented by &3s below
            "values": {
              "*": { // the level of the "values" array which is represented by &1s below 
                "@2,metric.hrStorageDescr": "&3.&1.hrStorageDescr",
                "@2,metric.hrStorageIndex": "&3.&1.hrStorageIndex",
                "@2,metric.instance": "&3.&1.instance",
                "@2,metric.job": "&3.&1.job",
                "0": "&3.&1.timestamp",
                "1": "&3.&1.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

or you can even do more dynamically by without hardcoding the subelements of the **"metric"** object such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "result": {
          "*": {
            "values": {
              "*": {
                "@2,metric": { "*": "&4[&2].&" },
                "0": "&3[&1].timestamp",
                "1": "&3[&1].value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the unwanted attribute
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "__name__": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Even better with the second solution, as I need to cope with different record fields for the metrics record, depending on the metric name. Superb!